# PHP issues with explode() and SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, explode

I have a code in PHP like the next:

```
    //$menutype is defined in this point, and no problem with it
    $sql = "SELECT struct FROM menutype WHERE id=$menutype;"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    list($struct) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $menu = explode("\n", $struct); //Explode to make an array with each line
    foreach ($menu as $index => $value)
    {
        //$barid is defined in the top of the document and no issue with it
        creatabla($barid, $value);
    }

function creatabla($barid, $tipo)
{
    $tipo = trim($tipo, ' '); //trim to delete unwanted spaces
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM products WHERE tipo LIKE '%$tipo%' AND restaurante='$barid';"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while(list($name) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
        echo "$name";
    }
}
```

Similar 'struct' row struct:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4AndLastLine
```

No car return after Last Line.

Well, the code usually works fine, but If I modify the 'Struct' row, some lines won't be read fine, so I usually need to edit the struct row in the advaced editor of the phpmyadmin.

What can I do to solve this issue? Can I try other kind of filter in the sql statement? What can I do to improve the trim or the explode function to solve this issue?

Thanks you to all in advance.

Comment: First of all, let me start with the mandatory warning not to use mysql_* functions. They are deprecated. You should be using mysqli_* or PDO functions instead. Your code above is ripe for SQL injection.

Comment: When you modify the `Struct` row you say "some lines won't be read fine" - what does that mean? Do 2 lines come out looking as if they are on the same line? Or are some lines ignored altogether? It might be helpful to do a `print_r($menu);` right after it is created.

Comment: It's appearing not diferences between a good line and a bad line :S

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Could you show an example of what happens (actual program output) when you have a bad line in the Struct row?

Comment: Hi, no differences between a good line and a bad line: I.e: I have a line with the next content: "Test1", the output says: "Test1", but the execution won't return anything with the sql query where tipo is Like %Test1%. If I edit Test1 line with the advanced editor of phpmyadmin, the output of each print_r are the same, but now, the code run successfully. I think it could be the end of the line, that the simply editor can add some weird end of line. :S

Comment: erk, your database is not normalized, and creating queries inside a loop driven by a query is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm starting to understand the issue and I'm guessing you're right - I'm guessing there is a \r character on the end.

Right now you are calling this:

```
trim($tipo, ' ');
```

That deletes *ONLY* spaces. If you change it to simply:

```
trim($tipo);
```

Then it will delete a lot more types of whitespace, including (but not limited to) the \r character.

[See HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) for more information on the `trim()` function.